# How can i make an object unmodifiable in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am having a configuration object in my flex3.5 application. I want that object to be unmodifiable so that no one can change any property in it once it is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a generic `Object`, it's impossible since it's dynamic.  What you want to do is create a class that has only 'getter' functions and every property is specified in the constructor.

If you want to have it still bindable, look at my blog post about [bindable read-only properties](http://www.michelboudreau.com/2009/09/09/bindable-read-only-property/).

Answer (score 1):

Use get/set methods. There is can be two strategies:

1. Private variables are initialized within class itself and every private variable has public get-method which makes public field read only.
2. If you need to set values from outside you should create set-methods and throw an error if value already set.